# Trying to remember a famous riddle

Tags: probability

There's a famous riddle that involves giving people a choice of 3 envelopes, one of which contains a dollar, and after the person selects an envelope one of the other two is removed and the person is given the option to switch. Is anyone familiar with this and what the math behind it is?

Comment: It's the Monty Hall problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem

Comment: It sounds like the Monty Hall problem, but it would only be equivalent if the envelope removed can be assumed to not contain the dollar.

Comment: @GavinSimpson yes the one removed if I remember correctly is the one that is empty